# Как лучше построить структуру БД и поиск?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, алгоритм

Всем добрый день. Есть не сложная задача - по API получаю список некоторых данных с текстом, категориями и т.д. 
Сейчас реализовано оповещение по категориям, напр. получил данные с категориями 1, 4, 55 - отсылаю оповещение пользователям, которые на эти категории подписаны.

В БД это выглдит так: таблица с категориями, и в каждой категории есть номер, и поле с id подписанных юзеров, например

234324|324524|24324|423432|432

И работает все отлично, перебираю категории, в каждой разбиваю строку на id и персонально отправляю сообщение. Но сейчас появилась идея создать подписку на ключевую строку, которая будет содержаться в описании, которое тоже приходит в ответе.

!не! слова, т.к. может быть слово *"мем"* а может быть *"мемы"*. При разбиении на слова через пробел - оба варианта будут приниматься как разные, а при поиске корня *мем* - оба варианта будут распознаны как нужные.

В чем проблема: если категория была однозначна - одно число, то текст уже нельзя разделить по пробелу и напрямую искать в бд, так как может быть текст как  *"мемы я лю"*, разбивать текст на ВСЕ возможные последовательности это бред.

Была мысль записать все ключевые строки, заданные пользователями в бд, все так же как и категории - но не искать в бд, а наоборот, вывести из БД все записи и проверять текст на содержание нужных строк. В начале это будет работать хорошо, но при огромном количестве ключевых строк, записанных в БД сервер явно начнет тормозить.

Вопрос: как лучше реализовать эту функцию? Есть варианты получше?

Comment: Используйте функции полнотекстового поиска. http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Fulltext_Search.html Если не достаточно - берите поисковые движки на подобии Elasticsearch

Comment: @Mike спасибо, даже не знал, что такое есть)